# SSLv3 handshake error with Python 3.3.3 Requests and Tomcat 7.0.47

Tags: java, python, tomcat, ssl, encryption

Having a problem with some client-side Python scripts after the latest upgrades to server:

Java 1.7.21 to 1.7.45

Tomcat 7.0.37 to 7.0.47

requests 1.2.3 AND 2.1.0 (both have this issue)

Centos 6.3 and 6.4

Openssl 1.0.1e-fips

```
File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-   
packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 95, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util.py", 
line 634, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 245, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 345, in __init__
    raise x
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 341, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 548, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure       (_ssl.c:550
```

This is our server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxHttpHeaderSize="65584"
        compression="on"
        compressionMinSize="2048"
        noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"

compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/xml,application/x-javascript,application/json"
        enableLookups="false"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        acceptCount="100"
        keystoreFile="conf/.keystore"
        maxThreads="250"
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        clientAuth="false"
        ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
        sslProtocol="SSL" />
```

I tested each cipher and found that these 4 always cause issues. I'm guessing priorities changed for these ciphers over older versions.

The 4 never work:

SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

I tried using the mount adapter method to force TSLv1 over SSLv3, but that doesn't seem to affect much of anything.

Finally my question is this: How can I tell my script to prefer or blacklist certain ciphers, if there's no fix to get the ciphers to actually work?

Obviously removing the ciphers from the server.xml would be easiest, but I don't know the impact that will have on browser access or security.

Edit: added versions of openssl, centos, and requests

Comment: `requests` is not part of the Python standard library, so just giving us the Python version doesn't help; we also need to know the `requests` version.

Comment: Also, in this case, it's important to know which OpenSSL version you have (and/or which version you built Python against), because IIRC the `ssl` module in Python 3.3.3 does TLS old-style if you have 0.9.8*, and does it right if you have 1.0.1b or later, but does it wrong if you're in between.

Comment: More information added as edit. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I don't have an answer here; hopefully someone else does. But a few vague ideas: If you've got OpenSSL 1.0.1e, I think forcing TLS over SSL3 is probably a good idea, if you can make that work. Also, do the same ciphers work against that server with a different client (not using Python's `ssl`), like `curl` or a browser? If not, maybe there's a different problem you need to fix.

Comment: Finally, in general, the stuff that isn't in the couple pages of `request` docs isn't just undocumented, it's not there; if you want to configure it to use different ciphers you will probably have to go under the covers to monkeypatch its embedded `urllib3` to use `http.client.HTTPSConnection` (from the stdlib) differently. If so, it's easier to figure out what you need to do by first building a simple test app using just pure `http.client` and get that working, then a `requests.packages.urllib3`-based test app, and then your real app.